# Eisenstein-type series

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, modular-forms

Is the series,
$$1 - 24\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{q^{2n}}{(1 - q^{2n})^2}, \quad q = e^{\pi i \tau}, \quad \textbf{I}[\tau] > 0,$$
somehow related to
$$E_2(q) = 1 - 24\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{nq^{2n}}{1 - q^{2n}}, \quad q = e^{\pi i \tau}, \quad \textbf{I}[\tau] > 0,$$
the Eisenstein series of weight 2?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that they are one and the same. In fact, it is very easy to establish.

Let $\sum$ denote the summation that runs over all the natural numbers. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_n \frac{q^{2n}}{(1 - q^{2n})^2} &= \sum_n \sum_m q^{2n} m q^{2n(m - 1)} \\
&= \sum_m \sum_n m q^{2nm} \\
&= \sum_m \frac{m q^{2m}}{1 - q^{2m}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: If you happen to enjoy such rearrangements, you can work out
$$\begin{align}
 \operatorname{E}_4
 &= 1 + 240\sum_{n=1}^\infty
  \frac{q^n}{(1-q^n)^2}
  \left(1 + 6\frac{q^n}{(1-q^n)^2}\right)
\\ \operatorname{E}_6
 &= 1 - 504\sum_{n=1}^\infty
  \frac{q^n}{(1-q^n)^2}\left(
  1 + 30\frac{q^n}{(1-q^n)^2}\left(
   1 + 4\frac{q^n}{(1-q^n)^2}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$
using $q = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$ here.

Comment: There is a general formula for $E_{2k}$ that sums polynomials of $q^n/(1-q^n)^2$.
It involves *central factorial numbers of the second kind with even index* ([OEIS A036969](http://oeis.org/A036969)). As a consequence, series summing polynomials of $q^n/(1-q^n)^2$ can be represented as linear combinations of Eisenstein series. Besides, those rearranged series converge also for $|q|>1$ (but not for $|q|=1$, therefore they do not provide an analytic continuation) and yield the same result as with $1/q$ instead of $q$.