# Properties of $\frac {\theta_{1}''(z|\tau)}{\theta_{1}(z|\tau)}$?

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I'm looking for references concerning the properties of the function $\frac {\theta_{1}''(z|\tau)}{\theta_{1}(z|\tau)}$ where $\theta_{1}(z|\tau)$ is a Jacobi theta function defined [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2.E1). I am trying to find special values of $z$ where I can rewrite this function in terms of modular forms (or maybe $E_2$) and other theta constants, or anything else that could appear there.

Comment: Do you have access to Whittaker and Watson: *A Course of Modern Analysis*? Still great.

Comment: You could build on [DLMF §20.5(ii) Logarithmic Derivatives](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.5.ii). Another approach is to use the heat PDE converting $''$ to $\mathrm{\partial}/{\partial}\tau$ and then (for $z=0$) proceeding [like there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372946/).

Comment: @ccorn thanks for your comments. I have access to Whittaker and Watson but was looking for a more hands on solution (shame on me indeed but I thought that this should be classic material). I am aware of the heat equation and the nice identities satisfied by the tau derivative of $\ln(\theta_i)$ for $i=2,3,4$. There is even one for $\theta_1'/\theta_1'''$ but somehow $\theta_1/\theta_1''$ is not really liked... But you're right I should just be brave and work it out myself it can't be that hard, especially because I know its Fourier-Jacobi expansion.

Comment: Yeah, the even-indexed derivatives of $\theta_1$ vanish at $z=0$, so you need to look at other $z$ (or other $\theta_j(0|\tau)$) there.

Comment: @ccorn but actually the ratio is finite and given by a certain q series which I can't really identify, but I'm interested in other points too. (btw in the previous comment I meant the reciprocal ratios).

Comment: Well, if you remember de l'Hopital, that gives you $\lim_{z\to0}\theta_1''(z|\tau)/\theta_1(z|\tau) = \theta_1'''(0|\tau)/\theta_1'(0|\tau)$.

Comment: ... and thus $-\operatorname{E}_2(\tau)$.

Comment: [Look there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900683) if you have trouble recognizing $\operatorname{E}_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notation:** I write
$$\begin{aligned}
    q_n &= \exp\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}{n}
&   q &= q_1
&   w &= \exp(\mathrm{i}z)
\\  \dot{(\ )}
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\left.\frac{\partial(\ )}{\partial\tau}\right|_z
    = \frac{q_n}{n}\left.\frac{\partial(\ )}{\partial q_n}\right|_w
&&& (\ )' &= \left.\frac{\partial(\ )}{\partial z}\right|_\tau
    = \mathrm{i} w \left.\frac{\partial(\ )}{\partial w}\right|_{q_n}
\end{aligned}$$
Note that the $q$ used in the [DLMF pages](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.1)
is written $q_2$ in this answer; their $q^2$ simplifies to $q$ here.

Expressions with $w$ and/or $q_n$ are implicitly regarded as functions of $z$
and/or $\tau$, respectively.

**Answer:** Given
$$\begin{aligned}
    \theta_1(z|\tau) &= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} q_8^{(2k+1)^2} (-\mathrm{i}w)^{2k+1}
    = 2q_8\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n(n+1)/2}\sin\left((2n+1)z\right)
\\  &= -\mathrm{i} w q_8\prod_{n=1}^\infty
    (1 - w^2 q^n)(1 - w^{-2} q^{n-1})(1 - q^n)
\\  &= 2q_8\sin(z)\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - w^2 q^n)(1 - w^{-2} q^n)(1 - q^n)
\end{aligned}$$
we can use the heat equation
$$\theta_1''(z|\tau) = -8\dot{\theta}_1(z|\tau)$$
and thus arrive at
$$\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\theta_1''(z|\tau)}{\theta_1(z|\tau)}
    &= -8\frac{\dot{\theta}_1(z|\tau)}{\theta_1(z|\tau)}
    = -8\left(\ln\theta_1(z|\tau)\right)^\cdot
\\  &= -8q\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial q}
    \ln\left(2q_8\sin(z)\prod_{n=1}^\infty
    (1 - w^2 q^n)(1 - w^{-2} q^n)(1 - q^n)\right)\right|_w
\\  &= -1 + 8\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\,w^2 q^n}{1 - w^2 q^n}
    + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\,w^{-2} q^n}{1 - w^{-2} q^n}
    + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\,q^n}{1 - q^n}\right)
\end{aligned}$$
In order to compress that expression, we apply the usual trick of
expanding the fractions to series, swapping the series nesting orders,
and simplifying the new inner series. Thus, for $|w^2 q| < 1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\,w^2 q^n}{1 - w^2 q^n}
    = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{m=1}^\infty w^{2m} q^{nm}
    = \sum_{m=1}^\infty w^{2m}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\,q^{nm}
    = \sum_{m=1}^\infty w^{2m}\frac{q^m}{(1 - q^m)^2}$$
Doing the same with the other series, we obtain
$$\frac{\theta_1''(z|\tau)}{\theta_1(z|\tau)}
= -1 + 8\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^m}{(1 - q^m)^2}\left(1 + 2\cos(2mz)\right)
\qquad (|\Im z| < \pi\,\Im\tau)$$
Note that the right-hand side has no singularity at $z=0$ and yields
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\theta_1''(z|\tau)}{\theta_1(z|\tau)} =
-1 + 24\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^m}{(1 - q^m)^2} = -\mathrm{E}_2(\tau)$$
which is quasimodular in $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks ! I ended up pretty much there with your comments. I should be able to figure out what other points are interesting, half periods etc.

Comment: Interestingly, the series representation implies $\frac{\theta_1''}{\theta_1}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\middle|\tau\right) = \frac{\theta_1''}{\theta_1}(0|3\tau) = -\mathrm{E}_2(3\tau)$.

Comment: (which fits nicely with the fact that $\sqrt{3}\,\eta(3\tau) = \theta_1\!\!\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\middle|\tau\right)$ where $\eta$ is the Dedekind eta function)